# D3 Linechart X-Axis displaying 00:00

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 multi-line chart. I want to display the time on x axis, but it is showing as 00:00 only.

Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
path { 
stroke-width: 1;
fill: none;
stroke-linejoin: round;
stroke-linecap: round;
}
circle { 
stroke-width: 1;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.legend, .label, .hover-text{
font-size: x-small;
background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select('svg'),
margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = +svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
g.append('text')
.attr('x', (width / 2))
.attr('y', 0 - (margin.top / 3))
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.style('font-size', '16px');
var parseTime = d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format('%e %B');
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width], 0.5);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function (d) {
    return x(d.date);
})
.y(function (d) {
    return y(d.worth);
});
d3.json("data1.json", function (error, data) {
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) {
return key !== "Time" && key !== "_id";
}));
data.forEach(function (d) {
d.date = parseTime(d.Time);
});
var currencies = color.domain().map(function (name) {
return {
name: name,
values: data.map(function (d) {
return {
    date: d.date,
    worth: +d[name]
};
})
};
});
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
console.log(d.date);
return d.date;
}));
y.domain([
d3.min(currencies, function (c) {
return d3.min(c.values, function (v) {
    return v.worth;
});
}),
d3.max(currencies, function (c) {
return d3.max(c.values, function (v) {
    return v.worth;
});
})
]);
g.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);
g.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end");
var currency = g.selectAll(".currency")
.data(currencies)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "currency");
currency.append("path")
.attr("class", "line")
.attr("d", function (d) {
    return line(d.values);
})
.style("stroke", function (d) {
    return color(d.name);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-03 23:00:00",
        "BTC": 19.7,
        "DOGE": 0,
        "ETH": 78.88
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-04 23:30:00",
        "BTC": 21.21,
        "DOGE": 0,
        "ETH": 90.45
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-05 24:00:00",
        "BTC": 20.1,
        "DOGE": 11.58,
        "ETH": 91.73
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-06 00:30:00",
        "BTC": 20.28,
        "DOGE": 12.37,
        "ETH": 92.78
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-09 01:00:00",
        "BTC": 21.77,
        "DOGE": 20.34,
        "ETH": 89.27
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-09 01:30:00",
        "BTC": 21.99,
        "DOGE": 20.58,
        "ETH": 88.62
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-09 02:00:00",
        "BTC": 22.46,
        "DOGE": 17.51,
        "ETH": 87.45
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-11 02:30:00",
        "BTC": 23.15,
        "DOGE": 18.83,
        "ETH": 86.94
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-11 03:00:00",
        "BTC": 24.17,
        "DOGE": 17.48,
        "ETH": 87.87
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-12 03:30:00",
        "BTC": 24.13,
        "DOGE": 17.99,
        "ETH": 88.05
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-13 04:00:00",
        "BTC": 22.41,
        "DOGE": 17.48,
        "ETH": 85.25
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-14 04:30:00",
        "BTC": 23.67,
        "DOGE": 17.04,
        "ETH": 89.19
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-14 05:00:00",
        "BTC": 23.47,
        "DOGE": 17.51,
        "ETH": 88.6
    },
        {
        "Time": "2017-05-14 05:30:00",
        "BTC": 23.67,
        "DOGE": 17.04,
        "ETH": 89.19
    },
    {
        "Time": "2017-05-14 06:00:00",
        "BTC": 23.47,
        "DOGE": 17.51,
        "ETH": 1000
    }
]
```

Comment: Remove the `tickFormat`: https://jsfiddle.net/7ubdf3qh/

Comment: If I remove tickFormat, it is displaying as Day.I want to display the time in x axis. (11:30 AM,12:00 PM,12:30 PM)

Comment: You asked *"I want to display the time"*. I don't want to be snarky or rude, but days are time. And about rudeness, you could at least say "thanks". I hope someone else help you.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. Now, this is your problem: your code **is** showing the time in hours, and it's showing them **correctly**. Those are midnights of different days. In D3, a time axis has its ticks automatically generated. On the other hand, if you want to show the hours:minutes for your data points, you'll ending up with this ugly axis: https://jsfiddle.net/jv0Lrmqh/. As you can see, the ticks are not nicely distributed, because your data set is not, in the first place. Therefore, for that data set, give up the idea of showing hours:minutes in the axis.

Comment: Thanks for your support. It works fine now... I have forget to tell one thing. We are going to show today's time only in x axis. Once again thanks for your support.